# profiling production flask application behind uwsgi+nginx

Tags: python, profiling, uwsgi

I have a flask application that runs behind uwsgi+nginx on linux (centos).

I want to profile the application to find bottle necks (time spent on each function).
This is a heavy application with 8 workers that run on production.

Though it seems quite elementary requirement, I have not found yet a good profiling system for production.

I have tried to use the python signal library to generate a profile as suggested in "https://www.nylas.com/blog/performance/" - but I have encountered a problem:
The signal() operation is allowed only on the main thread while the production uwsgi runs few workers. 
Further, from performance considerations we allow orphans, so running the operation on the master only wont do for the orphans.
Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

this is our uwsgi config:

```
    [uwsgi]
    vhost = true
    uid = vagrant

    base = /project/
    wsgi-file = /project/webserver/src/wsgi.py
    chdir = %(base)

    chown-socket = nginx:nginx
    catch-exceptions = true
    uid = nginx
    gid = nginx
    chmod-socket = 777
    socket = /var/run/webpage.com.uwsgi.socket
    plugin = python,dogstatsd
    #plugin = python
    master = True
    callable = app

    processes = 8
    threads = 24
    max-requests = 64
    #reload-on-as = 2000
    reload-mercy = 3600
    #reload-on-rss = 4000
    #limit-as = 10000
    cpu-affinity = 1
    #thread-stacksize = 1024
    max-fd = 250000
    #buffer-size = 30000
    thunder-lock = true
    vacuum = true
    enable-threads = true
    #no-orphans = true
    die-on-term = true
    #socket-timeout = 600
    #websocket-max-size = 16000
    #logto = /var/log/uwsgi/log.txt
    stats = /tmp/uwsgi_stats.socket
```

Comment: Did you solve this?